# Exception is not being thrown or test method is not recognizing the thrown exception?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, exception

[Here's the uml diagram of the Taxi class. There is another class name "Rank" that is why I set the property "rank" to have variable of a class called "Rank".]

[image: 1]

I have this test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void _07_SetRankToNullThrowsException()
{ 
    Taxi t = new Taxi(1);
    Assert.ThrowsException<Exception>(() => t.rank = null);
}
```

I'm supposed to throw an exception if "rank" is null which is clearly seen in this code but the test explorer just won't recognise the thrown exception or the exception is just isn't being thrown:

```
public string rank { 
    get { return rank; }
   
    set
    {

        if (rank == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Rank cannot be null");
        }
        else 
        {
            rank = null;
        }
        
    } 
    }
```

In the UML diagram, I'm supposed to make the property "rank" to have a variable of a class called "Rank.cs" (the code below) I've tried running this code as well but it also doesn't throw the exception.:

```
public Rank rank { 
    get { return rank; }
   
    set
    {

        if (rank == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Rank cannot be null");
        }
        else 
        {
            rank = null;
        }
        
    } 
}
```

Comment: Could you share the Taxi constructor? IE, is Taxi(1) setting the rank?

Also what is Rank? Is it a class or structure? Structures are value types and can never be null.

Comment: Sorry the two ranks confused me. For the first one, are you sure you don't have a compile error? C# is case sensitive. 'rank' and 'Rank' are not the same item names. But in your example code, you have `public string rank { get { return rank; }}`. This shouldn't compile or if it does, it should cause an infinite loop exception because that's what you have. Maybe you mean `public string Rank { get { return rank; }}` where 'Rank' is the property name and 'rank' is the private variable backing this property.

Comment: One last comment: So I created a new project with a class that had `public string rank { get { return rank; }}`. It does indeed compile, but as soon as I try to access that property I get a StackOverFlowException.

Comment: `if (rank == null)` should be `if (value == null)`

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that part of the problem may be in the naming - you have a property named `rank` in which you access the property itself to discover it's value.

In a property setter, the incoming value (the one being set) is accessed using the keyword `value`. You can use this to determine if the incoming value is `null` or not:

You also need to have a backing field to store the property value, which you haven't shown. Typically a backing field is private and is `camelCase`, while the associated property is `PascalCase`. This difference is helpful in this case because we can access `rank` from `Rank`.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
// Backing field to store the value for the 'Rank' property
private string rank = string.Empty;  // It could technically be set to 'null' here :)

public string Rank 
{ 
    get { return rank; }
   
    set
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Rank cannot be null");
        }
        else if (rank != value)
        {
            rank = value;
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are accessing your property in it's own getter, it is forever looping in itself. You can see this if you add code to write to console -

```
public Rank rank { 
    get 
    { 
         Console.WriteLine("uh oh"); //Here
         return rank; 
    }
   
    set
    {

        if (rank == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Rank cannot be null");
        }
        else 
        {
            rank = null;
        }
        
    } 
}
```

You'll see a massive amount of these written out.  You need to use a different name, and different variable to be the backing field to this property.